# nggrid table height fixes to 18 pixel error

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using nggrid and following is my code in list-orders.client.view.html

```
<section data-ng-controller="OrdersController" data-ng-init="find()">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Orders</h1>
  </div>
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</section>
```

I am using 2.0.12 version of nggrid

```
"devDependencies": {
    "ng-grid": "~2.0.12"
}
```

My table content's html is

```
<div class="ngViewport ng-scope" unselectable="on" ng-viewport="" 
ng-class="{'ui-widget-content': jqueryUITheme}" ng-style="viewportStyle()" tabindex="0" 
style="width: 1140px; height: 17px;">
     <!-- code for individual cells-->
</div>
```

How do I make sure the nggrid css values are not over written by my other css files included?

Comment: how you define the height in `gridStyle` class?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the width and height in `gridStyle` class

Comment: I got this solved using ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin. When the table is initialised, there was no data hence very small height but the height didnt change with change in size of data.

Comment: @raju - i think if you explicitly define the height in your `gridStyle` class, the height is fixed even for empty data

Comment: I didnt change gridStyle. Found this code http://plnkr.co/edit/tfS4Jce9XNRvM6hKqKq0?p=preview. It solved the styling issue